# insert values from select box into database mysql

Tags: mysql

Hi guys when i apply nothing Happens i check the table in mysql and it"s empty :/ 
i don't know what to do i think my code is right i don't know where is the problem and I'll be glade if you could just help and i want to add another thing if the value is already in the table i want ask the client to try again because the Appointment is already token 
php part

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
    // Fetch and clean the <select> value.
    // The (int) makes sure the value is really a integer.
    $qty = (int)$_POST['qantity'];

    // Create the INSERT query.
    $sql = "INSERT INTO rdv (time)
            VALUES ({$qty})";
    // Connect to a database and execute the query.
    $dbLink = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die(mysql_error());
              mysql_select_db('login') or die(mysql_errno());

    $result = mysql_query($sql);


    // Check the results and print the appropriate message.
    if($result) {
        echo "Record successfully inserted!";
    }
    else {
        echo "Record not inserted! (". mysql_error() .")";
    }
}
?>
```

Html part

```
 <html>
    <head>
        <title>Cabinet d'entaire</title>
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  media="all" />
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ropa+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link href="css/select.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  media="all" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <!--start-wrap-->

            <!--start-header-->
            <div class="header">
                <div class="wrap">
                <!--start-logo-->
                <div class="logo">
                    <a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.png" title="logo" /></a>
                </div>
                <!--end-logo-->
                <!--start-top-nav-->
                <div class="top-nav">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="services.html">services</a></li>
                        <li><a href="blog.html">blog</a></li>
                        <li><a href="contact.html">contact</a></li>
                    </ul>                   
                </div>
                <div class="clear"> </div>
                <!--end-top-nav-->
            </div>
            <!--end-header-->
        </div>
            <div class="clear"> </div>
           <div class="wrap">
            <div class="contact">
            <div class="section group">             
                <div class="col span_1_of_3">
                    <div class="contact_info">
                        <h2>Hi Patient</h2><br />
                            <div>
                                <li><img width="100%" height="210" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="images/patient.jpg" alt=""></li>
                            </div>
                    </div>

                </div>              
                <div class="col span_2_of_3">
                  <div class="contact-form">
                    <h2> Would you like to have Consultation or an Operation? </h2><br /> 
                        <form>

                           <div>
                           <div>
                        <span>Which day ?</span>
                                <span><input type="text" value=""></span>  <br />       
</div>
<label>
 <form action="id4.php" method="post">
   <select name="qantity">
        <option selected> choose Consultation Time  </option>
        <option value="9">  At 9</option>
        <option value="10">  At 10</option>
        <option value="11">  At 11</option>
        <option value="12">  At 12</option>
    </select>
</label>
<br /><br /> 
<br /><br /> 
<label>
    <select>
        <option selected> choose Operation Time  </option>
        <option>  At 14</option>
        <option>  At 15</option>
        <option>  At 16</option>
        <option>  At 17</option>
    </select>
</label>
 <div>
                                <br /> <span><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"></span>
                          </div>
                          </div>

                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>              
              </div>
                 <div class="clear"> </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"> </div>
            </div>
          <div class="clear"> </div>
           <div class="footer">
             <div class="wrap">
            <div class="footer-left">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="services.html">services</a></li>
                        <li><a href="blog.html">blog</a></li>
                        <li><a href="contact.html">contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="footer-right">
                <p>Medicare | Design By <a href="http://w3layouts.com/">W3Layouts</a></p>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"> </div>
           </div>
           </div>
        <!--end-wrap-->
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does `mysql_error()` say?

Comment: Be aware that half of your option values aren't INTs and are actually floats. Converting to INT will cause them to be rounded down (10.30 becomes 10, etc).

Comment: yes i will fix that thanks but the real problem is that i can't actually insert the values to the database :/

Comment: john conde it's says nothing when i apply it stay in the same page nothing happens :/

Comment: It would be helpful to be able to see the complete implementation of your form. Can you amend your question to show it please?

Comment: is't enough now sir ?

Comment: That HTML is packed with missing end tags. Use a [validator](http://validator.w3.org).

Comment: not that is the principale of my select box ..because just a part of the page that i'm working in if i try to copy all the page code it will be long so i just copied the important thing that has the problem

Comment: Can you add the whole HTML form to the question? I suspect `$_POST['qantity']` is a typo and there may be others

Comment: alastair McCormack now ?

Comment: Have you done a `var_dump($_POST);` to see what values it contains?

Comment: no can you please give me an example ?

Comment: please i do really need an answer :/

Comment: ``if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
{
    var_dump($_POST);
}``

Comment: Is it possible the database table has some constraints (like a NOT NULL field) that your insert statement isn't meeting, thus causing the insert to fail?  Can you post the results of "SHOW CREATE TABLE rdv"?

Comment: rdv  CREATE TABLE `rdv` (
 `times` float NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

Comment: i've created another table and still not working :/